# como enviar más de un registro a una tabla temporal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente Código para enviar información a una tabla temporal

```
Declare @NumOperador INT , @FechaDesde Datetime, @FechaHasta Datetime, @Jornada_Ini DATETIME, @Jornada_Fin DATETIME,
@FinJornada DATETIME, @DescansoJornada DATETIME, @DiasTrabajados INT, @DescansosOtorgados INT,
@DiasDescansados INT, @DiasDescanso INT, @TotalDias INT, @Descanso INT, @DiasLaborales INT

set @NumOperador=451083
set @FechaDesde='2017-05-01'
set @FechaHasta='2017-05-31'    


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpDescansos') Is Not Null DROP TABLE #tmpDescansos 

CREATE TABLE #tmpDescansos (NumOperador INT, JornadaInicial DATETIME,  FinJornada DATETIME,  DescansoJornada  DATETIME, DescansosOtorgados INT) 
Select
       @NumOperador=CC.NumOperador
       @Jornada_Ini=Jornada_Ini,
       @Jornada_Fin=@FechaHasta,
       @DiasLaborales=J.DiasLabores ,
       @FinJornada=DATEADD(DAY, J.DiasLabores, CC.Jornada_Ini-1),
       @DescansoJornada=DATEADD(DAY, J.DiasDescanso, CC.Jornada_Fin),
       @DiasDescanso=j.DiasDescanso,
       @DescansosOtorgados= ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @FinJornada, 
       @DescansoJornada)),         
       @DiasTrabajados=DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaDesde, @FechaHasta+1),
       @TotalDias= J.diastotal 
FROM trkOperadores O 
JOIN trkJornada J ON O.cveJornada=J.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON O.NumOperador = CC.NumOperador
    WHERE (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)
    AND Jornada_Ini <= @FechaHasta  
    group by CC.NumOperador, CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, J.DiasDescanso, CC.Jornada_Fin, J.diastotal

WHILE (@Jornada_Ini<=@FechaHasta)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #tmpDescansos VALUES(@NumOperador, 
@Jornada_Ini,@FinJornada,@DescansoJornada, @DescansosOtorgados)
SET @Jornada_Ini=@Jornada_Ini+@TotalDias
SET @FinJornada=(@Jornada_Ini-1)+@DiasLaborales
SET @DescansoJornada=@FinJornada+@DiasDescanso
END

select* from #tmpDescansos
```

Cuando yo envío numero del Operador 451083 me envía la información a la tabla Temporal.
[image: Operador 451083]

Si yo envió el numero de operador 0 para que me envié todos los operadores de la tabla, me regrese en 900200 todo y no por cada numero de operador

[image: Numero de Operador 900200]

Comment: Gracias, modifique el operador y coloque el numoperador, me había faltado una línea una disculpa ya la ingrese en la pregunta, ahora en lugar de darme 0 me da un solo operador 900200 @sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque no tengo ningún detalle en cuanto a tus datos y lo que estás tratando de realizar, aun así es obvio que el diseño de tus operaciones es incorrecto.

Asumiendo que se supone que la consulta siguiente te devuelve más de un registro con diferentes valores para la columna `NumOperador`:

```
Select
       @NumOperador=CC.NumOperador
       @Jornada_Ini=Jornada_Ini,
       @Jornada_Fin=@FechaHasta,
       @DiasLaborales=J.DiasLabores ,
       @FinJornada=DATEADD(DAY, J.DiasLabores, CC.Jornada_Ini-1),
       @DescansoJornada=DATEADD(DAY, J.DiasDescanso, CC.Jornada_Fin),
       @DiasDescanso=j.DiasDescanso,
       @DescansosOtorgados= ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @FinJornada, 
       @DescansoJornada)),         
       @DiasTrabajados=DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaDesde, @FechaHasta+1),
       @TotalDias= J.diastotal 
FROM trkOperadores O 
JOIN trkJornada J ON O.cveJornada=J.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON O.NumOperador = CC.NumOperador
    WHERE (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)
    AND Jornada_Ini <= @FechaHasta  
    group by CC.NumOperador, CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, J.DiasDescanso, CC.Jornada_Fin, J.diastotal
```

... toma en cuenta que al concluir la consulta, todas las variables (`@NumOperador`, `@Jornada_Ini`, etc...) obtendrán sus valores del **último** registro que devuelva la consulta.  Los valores obtenidos de todos los registros anteriores serán completamente perdidos e ignorados.  Es casi seguro que esto no es lo que quieres.

Y, debido a lo antedicho, cuando efectues el bloque de código siguiente:

```
WHILE (@Jornada_Ini<=@FechaHasta)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #tmpDescansos VALUES(@NumOperador, 
@Jornada_Ini,@FinJornada,@DescansoJornada, @DescansosOtorgados)
SET @Jornada_Ini=@Jornada_Ini+@TotalDias
SET @FinJornada=(@Jornada_Ini-1)+@DiasLaborales
SET @DescansoJornada=@FinJornada+@DiasDescanso
END
```

... el valor para `@NumOperador` simplemente será el que obtuvistes con el último registro de tu consulta anterior.

Sin conocer más detalles de tus datos y lo que estás tratando de hacer en realidad, lo mejor que puedo hacer es recomendarte de modificar el diseño de tu código:

No uses un bucle `WHILE` para insertar tus datos. Mas bien, modifica tu código para combinar tu `SELECT` con la sentencia `INSERT` (`INSERT INTO #tmpDescansos (...) SELECT ...`)

Comment: ahora entiendo más,  si el registro que me envía es el ultimo como me lo estas aclarando, agradezco mucho tu explicación, voy a modificar mi código, espero no tener algún detalle ya que aun estoy en proceso de aprendizaje. Gracias @sstan